# Programmatically Navigate in Navigation Drawer set up with Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

Can anyone help me out with this?

I currently have a Navigation Drawer that is setup with Navigation Component in my  `MainActivity`

Code:

```
   val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.fragment1,
                R.id.fragment2,
                R.id.fragment3
            
            ), layoutDrawer
        )

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

**What I want:**

I want to programmatically navigate to a specific fragment without the use of `R.id.action` since I will be writing the code in the `MainActivity` which is not part of my `NavGraph`

Something like

```
navController.navigate(R.id.fragment3)
```

would be nice

Comment: Already you can use the fragment id like the example you shared

Comment: Wow, how dumb of me.  I never bothered to try cause it might crash the app.

Comment: Also trying to do this now. But if I use navController.navigte(fragment2), then select the first fragment again from the drawer menu - it goes directly to fragment2 instead.

Comment: Yes I also encountered this @Zee, It seems like the fragment2 in your example is not being cleared - going to the first fragment is being done in the back of the fragment2. Pressing the  back button will show the first fragment implying that it is indeed in back of fragment2.

Comment: Hmm, after re-reading your question, I think I actually misunderstood what you were trying to do (as I am actually using my navigation graph). My bad!